# Spring MVC navigation not working as expected

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring MVC application which uses the RequestMapping annotation.

I have my annotations mapped to several pages likes: /newStudent, /saveStudent etc.

When I run my application, my Url is:

```
https://localhost:8001/MyWebApp/index.jsp
```

When I click on the links which should navigate to these values in RequestMapping, instead of the URL becoming: 
    https://localhost:8001/MyWebApp/newStudent/
    https://localhost:8001/MyWebApp/saveStudent,

it goes to:

```
    https://localhost:8001/newStudent/
    https://localhost:8001/saveStudent/,
```

My serverlet mapping looks like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Why is the application name being dropped? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your controller `RequestMapping` values.

Comment: Add an example of what a link looks like (from your jsp's)

Comment: add controller class code